# QListView with QStandardItemModel does not show selection highlight through code

Tags: qt, qlistview, qstandarditemmodel

I have a `QListView` that is populated with either a `QStandardItemModel` or a `QStringListModel` (based on simplicity of contents... number of columns).

On load, or switching between widgets, I search for the item that should be selected, and try to highlight it.

```
if (first)
{
    m_myListView.setModel(m_standardItemModel);

    QList<QStandardItem*> lst = m_standardItemModel->findItems(m_value1, Qt::MatchExactly, 1);
    if(!lst.isEmpty())
    {
        QModelIndex index = lst.at(0)->index();
        qDebug() << index.row();                  // tells me correct row
        //m_myListView.setCurrentIndex(index);    // no change if I use
        m_myListView.selectionModel()->select(index, QItemSelectionModel::ClearAndSelect);
        m_myListView.scrollTo(index);
    }
}
else
{
    m_myListView.setModel(m_stringListModel);

    int i = m_stringListModel->stringList().indexOf(m_value2);
    if (i >= 0)
    {
        QModelIndex index = m_stringListModel->index(i);
        m_myListView.selectionModel()->select(index, QItemSelectionModel::ClearAndSelect);
        m_myListView.scrollTo(index);
    }
}
```

The `m_stringListModel` version correctly highlights (and scrolls to item).
The `m_standardItemModel` version does not highlight row, and does not scroll to item. But in the uses afterwards, it correctly provides the data for selected index:

```
QModelIndexList indexList = m_myListView.selectionModel()->selectedIndexes();
if (!indexList.isEmpty())
{
    QModelIndex index = indexList.first();
    if (index.isValid())
    {
        row = index.row();
        data1 = m_standardItemModel->index(row, 1).data().toString();
```

...

So... it seems that the selection works, but if it does, why do I not see a highlight ? (and the `scrollTo()` )

Note - the code is pretty giant but I verified for the possibility of reloading the model and possibly losing the selection - and besides, the `QStringListModel` version works correctly.

Is that a typical behavior of `QStandardItemModel`, or is there something I must do, like setting a `BackgroundRole` type data ?

How can I highlight the selection of the list view with the `QStandardItemModel` applied ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the item found is different than the display item, the list view is unable to select it...

2 solutions: either create a different `QModelIndex` from the one found, pointing to the display column, or select an entire row containing the desired index:

```
m_myListView.selectionModel()->select(index, QItemSelectionModel::ClearAndSelect | QItemSelectionModel::Rows);
```

Answer (score 1):

I see your code, probably you want to select the first element of your model?  Let's try:

```
void MyClass::selectFirstElement() {
     const QModelIndex firsIndex = _myModel->index(0,0);
     if (index.isValid())
         ui->listView->setCurrentIndex(firstIndex);
         ui->listView->scrollTo(firstIndex);
     }
```

}

Could you share the m_standardItemModel implementation? Also configure your list correctly:

```
ui->listView->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
ui->listView->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows); // Or Columns
```

Check if your QStandarItem has the selection [flag](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstandarditem.html#setFlags) enable. See http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#ItemFlag-enum for more info.

Finally, you could ensure that the index is stored in the correct model by getting the index in the same row & column directly from the model, something like this:

```
QModelIndex index = lst.at(0)->index();
index = _model->index(index.row(), index.column());
```

Sorry, for my poor english :S